# unable to get ng-checked property for a radio button to check the button when populating a form

Tags: angularjs

EDIT: for those of you who don't want to go through the code, I'm basically passing the form a "node" object with node.selectedAnswer = "4,1,4" or some string like that.  The form has radio buttons and one of the buttons has a value "4,1,4".  the radio button also has ng-checked="node.selectedAnswer" expression.  But that doesn't work.  I know for sure that node.selectedAnswer has the appropriate value.

I have a series of radio button questions that I'm asking the user.  I want them to be able to go previous and next.  I'm using a stack to store the data retrieved from ajax call, as well as selectedAnswer when they select an option and click next.  I've commented the code itself to explain the situation where I can.  Everything seems to be working, except ng-checked is just not picking up node.selectedAnswer, even though I can output {{node.selectedAnswer}} properly to the page.

```html
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-app="AccountRequest" ng-controller="GameNode" ng-init="outside={}">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span10">
            <form>
                <!-- node.selectedAnswer displays the selectedAnswer correctly when clicking previous and going back.
                    However, ng-checked is somehow not selecting the appropriate radio button. -->
                <span>{{node.Question.Text}} selected answer: {{node.selectedAnswer}}</span>
                <div class="radio" ng-repeat="answer in node.Answers">
                    <input type="radio" id="answerGroup" name="answerGroup" ng-checked="node.selectedAnswer" ng-model="outside.selectedAnswer" 
                           value="{{answer.BranchId}},{{node.LeafId}},{{answer.Id}}"/> {{answer.Text}} 
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="button" ng-click="previous()" value="Previous"/>
                    <input type="button" ng-click="next(outside.selectedAnswer)" value="Next"/>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//below is the script

```js
    app.controller('GameNode', function ($scope, $http) {
    var nodes = [];

    function load(branchId, leafId, answerId) {
        $http.get("/AccountRequest/GetNode?branchId=" + branchId +
            "&leafId=" + leafId +
            "&answerId=" + answerId)
            .success(function (data) {
                //get data and push it in the stack
                nodes.push(data);
                $scope.node = data;
            });
    }

    function populateValues(selectedAnswer) {
        var answer = null;

        if (selectedAnswer === undefined || selectedAnswer == null)
            selectedAnswer = "0,0,0";

        //when next is clicked, retrieve the selectedAnswer from form and store it in current node as a property.
        if (nodes.length > 0) {
            var curNode = nodes.pop();
            curNode.selectedAnswer = selectedAnswer;
            nodes.push(curNode);
        }

        answer = selectedAnswer.split(','); 

        if (answer != null) {
            load(answer[0], answer[1], answer[2]);    
        }
    }

    $scope.next = populateValues;
    $scope.previous = function () {
        //when previous is clicked, pop the current node out and throw it away.
        //then pop the previous node out, read it, and push it back in as current node.
        if (nodes.length > 1) {
            nodes.pop();
            var prevNode = nodes.pop();
            nodes.push(prevNode);
            $scope.node = prevNode;
        }
    };
    populateValues();
});
```

Comment: use ng-true-value and ng-false-value

Comment: just tried it.  doesn't work.

Comment: How many radios are there? It looks like they all have the same id, which should be unique....? Not sure if that would break your code, though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Older Answer -** *This works, (was marked correct) but using `$parent` can get a bit messy in nested repeats.*

In this instance, you don't need to use ng-checked at all.  Since this is a radio group, the checked attribute will be bound to the model.  If the model is bound to the value of an individual radio button, then your ability to change which button is "checked" becomes very simple.

[Here is a plunk that demonstrates the concept.](http://plnkr.co/edit/8wQ0frHmuI1EbBCZBv5N?p=preview)

So in your case a few changes need to be made.
1.  Get rid of 'id' attribute - the ID must be unique for each element.
2.  Each item created in an ng-repeat creates its own child scope.  So to access the original model, "$parent" must be invoked.

```
<input type="radio" name="answerGroup" ng-model="$parent.someAnswerAttribute" 
 value="{{answer.BranchId}},{{node.LeafId}},{{answer.Id}}"/>
```

In your controller define the model as you already did, then modify it to be tied to a value of a button, which in your case will be a bit lengthy, since you have multiple attributes within your value.

```
$scope.someAnswerAttribute = // exactly what the value of a radio button would be.
```

Again, the plunker above reflects this concept.  Hope this helps!

..

---

..

**Edit - Better Answer:**

Since the ng-repeat creates its own child scope, and two-way binding is necessary, the `ng-model` should be referencing an *object* instead of a *primitive*.  In other words, if the model was `$scope.myModel="Biff"`, the child scope can not access that without invoking `$parent` (in the answer below).  However, if the model is referencing a property of an object, the child will receive prototype inheritance of that object. (I think I said that right).

So using the older answer example, we can change:

From this in the parent controller:

```
$scope.someAnswerAttribute = "Biff";
```

To this in the parent controller:

```
$scope.someAnswerAttribute = {value: "Biff"}
```

And in the radio group:

```
<input type="radio" name="answerGroup" ng-model="someAnswerAttribue.value" 
 value="{{answer.BranchId}},{{node.LeafId}},{{answer.Id}}"/>
```

[This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/viIrHqXA5ZmwdkN0gGQB?p=preview) is forked from the older answer and demonstrates model as an object property.

Comment: worked like a charm.  I was using $parent originally, but somebody on stackoverflow had advised not to use $parent.  That's why I was using ng-init="outside={}".  Can you suggest how to make it work without using $parent?